# Using C++ in R compling error: "RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

```
$ export PKG_CPPFLAGS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()'`
$ export PKG_LIBS=`Rscript -e 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'`
$ R CMD SHLIB my.cpp 
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c my.cpp -o my.o
my.cpp:3:27: fatal error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [my.o] Error 1
```

My `RcppArmadillo.h` is under

```
$ locate -i RcppArmadillo.h
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h
```

I wonder how to specify its path to the compiler?

`my.cpp` looks like:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <math.h> 

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
...
```

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. R is R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10). I just installed `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`, so I guess they are also the most recent ones.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Usually I put the depends before the includes.

Comment: @Roland: Problem remains after moving `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` before `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` and `#include <math.h> `. Is that what you suggested?

Comment: location of `Rcpp::depends` is irrelevant. The problem here is that the generated code does not get generated. see my answer.

Comment: Please read the fine vignette [Rcpp Attributes](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) to see how this is meant to be used. You are assuming you can simply mix two approaches (pure compilation and use of helper infrastructure), and the fact is that you can't (and we never said you could). If you insist on `R CMD SHLIB` you have to let go of `sourceCpp()` and fall back to using the [inline](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=inline) package.

Comment: thanks, @Dirk! By two approaches, do you mean using Rcpp attributes by "use of helper infrastructure", and mean `R CMD SHLIB` by pure compilation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot just `R CMD SHLIB` this file. Because you use Rcpp attributes, you need some code to be generated from `Rcpp::depends` and `Rcpp::export`.

You can either call `sourceCpp( 'my.cpp' )` from R if you just want standalone use of the file or use various tools such as `compileAttributes` or `devtools::load_all` if this file is part of a package you are developping.

But `R CMD SHLIB` is not going to generate the extra code for you.

Something I have on my `$PATH` and find quite useful is this `RcppScript` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)

if( "-v" %in% args ){
  options( verbose = TRUE )
}

library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp( tail(args,1) )
```

So that you can do:

```
$ RcppScript my.cpp
```